# Close IE and Open Chrome, only runs once and then crashes

Tags: vb.net, managementeventwatcher

I have the below very simple script

```
Imports System.Management
Imports System

Module Module1
Dim watcher As ManagementEventWatcher

Sub Main()

    Dim monitoredProcess = "iexplore.exe"
    Dim query As WqlEventQuery = New WqlEventQuery("__InstanceCreationEvent", New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), "TargetInstance isa ""Win32_Process"" And TargetInstance.Name = """ & monitoredProcess & """")

    watcher = New ManagementEventWatcher()
    watcher.Query = query
    watcher.Start()

    watcher.WaitForNextEvent()

    For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore")
        p.Kill()
    Next

    Process.Start(New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("Chrome", "http://google.com"))

End Sub

End Module
```

Which should monitor when an ie window is opened, close it and run chrome instead. This works great the first time, but once it has completed it crashes with the following error

```
An unhandled exception of type     'System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException' occurred in System.Management.dll

Additional information: COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used.
```

What can I do to stop the com from separating? I would like the program to start with windows and continue to run all the time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this be basically creating a loop

```
Imports System.Management
Imports System

Module Module1
Dim watcher As ManagementEventWatcher

Sub Main()

    Dim monitoredProcess = "iexplore.exe"
    Dim query As WqlEventQuery = New WqlEventQuery("__InstanceCreationEvent", New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), "TargetInstance isa ""Win32_Process"" And TargetInstance.Name = """ & monitoredProcess & """")

    watcher = New ManagementEventWatcher()
    watcher.Query = query
    watcher.Start()

    watcher.WaitForNextEvent()

    For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore")
        p.Kill()
    Next

    Process.Start(New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("Chrome", "http://google.com"))

    watcher.Stop()
    watcher.Dispose()

    Main()

End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Not a loop. That's a recursive call, and if this program is meant to run for an extended amount of time, it could end up causing problems. Specifically a stack overflow. You could use a while loop instead of the recursion.

Comment: Thanks, ill monitor it for today and see if I hit any issues.